# What does X mean in American History X?

Tags: title, american-history-x

In the movie title American History X, what exactly does X represent?

I could think of Roman numeral X (10) or generation x, however, I don't seem to fully understand the meaning.

Answer (score 7):

There are [some possible answers here](http://www.oocities.org/sunsetstrip/club/3036/faq.html):

> The "X" is there to stand for all the things we want to hide.
>   (Remember the X-files). It has nothing to do with Malcolm X but the X
>   in Malcolm X is also to hide something. The last name of Malcolm X was
>   a white man last name and he wanted to hide it.
>
> ---
>
> I disagree with your statement about what the X stands for in the
>   title of the movie as well as the X-files and Malcolm X. X stands for
>   the unknown. In the Autobiography of Malcolm X he explains that since
>   he was given a white man's name he never knew his real last name.
>   hence he changed it to X to symbolize the unknown. also the x files
>   are called the x files because they are reports on the unknown
>   behavior of the paranormal and supernatural.
>
> ---
>
> Maybe the "X" has something to do with the graphical ressemblance with
>   a swastika symbol, as well.
>
> ---
>
> As a college student, I see this often. When the university starts a
>   class and it is still in the experimental stage, it is given a course
>   number followed by an X.... for instance, CompSci403X. The X indicates
>   that it is a new course and that changes are still being made. I think
>   that Sweeney was thinking of this method when he named Danny's class
>   "American History X". Danny's class was new, experimental,
>   individualized, and certainly not a part of his original curriculum.

Comment: The first point seems to make most sense, implying something like "untold things" from American history.

Comment: The X-files are called the X-files because they were originally filed under U for unsolved but they started running out of room so they moved the unsolved files to the X drawer where there was plenty of room. See the following post at [SciFi SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107461/who-came-up-with-the-term-x-files-in-universe) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you recall the scene in which Danny (Edward Furlong) hands in his paper titled "My Mein Kampf", his principal (Avery Brooks) informs him that he will now teach Danny one-on-one in a class titled "American History X".  The X is meant to stand for "New", just like its usage in "Generation X".  This is a re-education of Danny in which he will be forced to see History from a new angle, in an effort to change his thought process.